# Include static files in a reusable Razor Class Library

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-class-library

I am trying to make a reusable class library (RCL) that I can use in several ASP.NET Core MVC projects. So far so good… until I try to include the required JavaScript in the RCL. There is little-to-no documentation about this topic. My best shot was to [try this example](https://github.com/sheng-jie/RPL.Demo).

But when I do, I get the following error when I build the library:

[image]

This is the project file and the structure of the library:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that now, with the release of ASP.NET Core 3.0, the ability to embed static resources in Razor Class Libraries (RCL) is now built into the framework and enabled by default without needing to fuss with configuring file providers. The way files are referenced is different, and they no longer act as fallbacks that can be overwritten, but the implementation is much nicer overall.

Comment: @JeremyCaney those are very good news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I have some spare time I will answer my own question. Maybe it will useful for someone.

Finally I solved this problem using `EmmbededResources` without the `EmbeddedFilesManifest` as [ianbusko pointed out in Github](https://github.com/ianbusko/reusable-components-library).

First I created an extension for the `IApplicationBuilder` class:

```
namespace Dashboard.Lib.Extensions
{
    public static class IApplicationBuilderExtension
    {
        public static void UseDashboardScripts(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            var embeddedProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Areas.Dashboard.ViewComponents.DashboardViewComponent)
                .GetTypeInfo().Assembly, "Dashboard.Lib.Scripts");

            builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = embeddedProvider,
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Scripts")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the javascript files to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>false</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="2.1.1" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Scripts/**/**/**/*" Pack="true" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

In the RCL view the javascript is included as follows:

```
@section Scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/pagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/checkdigit-validator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/rut-validation.js"></script>
}
```

Finally in the Statup.cs in the main MVC project you just have to include the following:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDashboardScripts();
```